# issue in checkbox of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

```
<div ng-repeat="n in mysize"
 <input type="checkbox" id="ckl_{{n.id}}" ng-model="n[id].checked"
                                    ng-change="selectSizeEdit(p.size_arr,n.id)" ng-if="(p.size_arr.indexOf(n.id) > -1)" ng-checked="true"> 
</div>
```

In the above code the values inside p.size_arr in checkboxes will be checked. Bt i cant select new checkboxes other than in p.size_arr. Plz help me.

Comment: Would you create a fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model="n[id].checked"` is probably wrong, could you try `ng-model="n.checked"`?

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle then ? We can't really do much with this information